# How to get object values and id as an option for a select box use javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this:

```
var quantites = {
   4: {
        93: {
            "id": "355",
            "qty": 8
        }
    },
   5: {
        93: {
            "id": "356",
            "qty": 10
       }
    },
 };
```

How can I get the id as value and qty as label in an select without using/knowing the keys to loop through:

```
<option value="335">8</option>
<option value="336">10</option>
```

To a div:

```
<div id="qty">
    <select></select>
</div>
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
            $.each(quantites, function(key, value) {
            $('#qty')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value)); 
            });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: is id and qty always at the 3rd level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first transform your data to array of objects and then use `forEach` loop to add to `select`

```js
var quantites = {"4":{"93":{"id":"355","qty":8}},"5":{"93":{"id":"356","qty":10}}}

var select = $('#qty select')
var data = [].concat(...Object.values(quantites).map(Object.values))
data.forEach(function(e) {
  select.append(`<option value="${e.id}">${e.qty}</option>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qty">
    <select></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, the only thing I'd suggest is not to append within the loop. You'd rather construct the HTML string in the loop and append outside.

Answer (score 1):

If your object(s) containing id and qty are always on the 3rd level and there are no other objects you can convert your current object into an array of objects that have id and qty:

```
var quantites = {
   4: {
        93: {
            "id": "355",
            "qty": 8
        }
    },
   5: {
        93: {
            "id": "356",
            "qty": 10
       }
    },
 };

var arrayOfQuantities = 
Object.keys(quantites)
.map(
  key => 
    Object.keys(quantites[key])
    .map(subKey => quantites[key][subKey])
)
.reduce((acc,item) => acc.concat(item),[])
```

It may be better to address how you get such an unusable object in the first place and fix that problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this post?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114672/reducing-a-large-array-of-objects-to-a-simple-object-with-8-properties

you could reduce the larger object to just the bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var quantites = {
   4: {
        93: {
            "id": "355",
            "qty": 8
        }
    },
   5: {
        93: {
            "id": "356",
            "qty": 10
       }
    },
 };
 var htmltoAppend;
 for (var key in quantites){
    for(var key2 in quantites[key])
    htmltoAppend = `<option value="` + quantites[key][key2].id + `">`+ quantites[key][key2].qty +`</option>`;
    document.getElementById('qty').append(htmltoAppend);
 }
```